# Hangfire does not recognize or connect to SQL Server in Razor Pages application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, localdb

I'm attempting to add Hangfire to my existing Razor Pages ASP.NET Core 6 Application. I already have two existing databases that are connecting and operating properly (Business logic DB and Identity DB). After adding the recommended configurations from the docs, the application runs fine but when I try to go to the Hangfire dashboard, I get an error stating the database does not exist. I tried adding the Database manually but it gave me the same error. The database is running locally and I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio for it. I did find that I needed to call app.UseSession() before mapping the endpoints, or it would break the rest of my application as well, so I'm not sure if that is related.

I do suspect it has something to do with HttpContext but it's crucial that I keep that service as I use it throughout the application. More likely, I'm making some rookie error that I just don't see since I'm still not very experienced with all of this yet.

Here is the connection string I am using in appsettings.json

```
"HangfireConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLocalDB;Database=Hangfire;Integrated Security=SSPI; Trusted_Connection=True"
```

and my program.cs file

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RentARouter.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using RentARouter.Areas.Identity.Data;
using RentARouter.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.SqlServer;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

/*************************************************************
 * Connect to identity database and set options
 *************************************************************/
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityDBContextConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'IdentityDBContextConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityDBContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));;
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<RentARouterUser>(options =>
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDBContext>();

//sets idle time and default pages
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);

    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

/*************************************************************
 * Connect to business logic database
 *************************************************************/
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
        ));
/*************************************************************
 * Add addtl services to the application
 *************************************************************/
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();


/*************************************************************
 * Add Distributed Memory Cache and Session services
 *************************************************************/
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

builder.Services.AddTransient<CacheService>();

/*************************************************************
 * Add Transaction Logging Services
 *************************************************************/
builder.Services.AddTransient<TransactionService>();

/*************************************************************
 * Add Hangfire Service
 *************************************************************/
builder.Services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
.UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
.UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
.UseSqlServerStorage(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection"), new SqlServerStorageOptions
{
    CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
    UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
    DisableGlobalLocks = true
}));
builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();

/*************************************************************
 * Build the web application
 *************************************************************/
var app = builder.Build();

/*************************************************************
 * Configure the HTTP request pipeline
 *************************************************************/
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();;
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard();
});

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

And the error I am recieving

```
SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. The specified LocalDB instance does not exist. )
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, object providerInfo, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, uint waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, bool allowCreate, bool onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, out DbConnectionInternal connection)
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource<DbConnectionInternal> retry)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.CreateAndOpenConnection()
Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.UseConnection<T>(DbConnection dedicatedConnection, Func<DbConnection, T> func)
Hangfire.Dashboard.Pages.HomePage.Execute()
Hangfire.Dashboard.RazorPage.TransformText(string body)
Hangfire.Dashboard.RazorPageDispatcher.Dispatch(DashboardContext context)
Hangfire.Dashboard.AspNetCoreDashboardMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.UsePathBaseMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext context, PathString matchedPath, PathString remainingPath)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

EDIT:
THis was fixed thanks to Charlie's comments below. I just needed to change my localDB to a shared instance.

Comment: SQL Server LocalDB usually runs within a single user's session, so each cannot see the other. Either create a database under the user of the IIS app pool, or change the app pool user to the other user, or change your current database to a shared database. Also LocalDB has an auto shutdown timer, you might want to configure that

Comment: The current DB I'm using is only for development. Everything has been working so far, until adding hangfire, since I'm the only one accessing it. Long term I'll be moving everything to a hosted SQL db. Do you think using LocalDB is what is causing my issue? I checked the docs and it says it should work with LocalDB

Comment: Yes it should, you just need to do one of those options that I said and it will work. IIS applications normally run as a different user (not your normal admin user) and LocalDB by default runs separately per user. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16#shared-instances-of-localdb

Comment: So, I must be missing something. I had MSSql Management Studio installed which is how I set up the initial DB. When I try to open SQLLocalDB utility, it apeared SQL Server Express was not installed. I installed SQl Server Express and now I have two databases in Management Studio.

The one I already had
`MSI\LOCALDB#6BF3D7FA`

and now:
`MSI\SQLEXPRESS`

And I can't for the life of me get SQLLocalDB utility to run, or find an option in MSSQL Managament Studio to make one of these a "shared" databse.

Comment: Well....I was able to get this far:
`C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqllocaldb h ["MSSQLLocalDB"] localDB
Private LocalDB instance "[MSSQLLocalDB]" shared with the shared name: "localDB".`

I'm guessing I now need to change my connection string but can't seem to figure out what the right change is to connect to the new shared version of the db

Comment: `SQLEXPRESS` was not necessary, it is a separate, full installation of SQL Server, rather than the lightweight LocalDB. Apparently the server name should be `(localdb)\.\LOCALDB#6BF3D7FA` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16#connect-to-a-shared-instance-of-localdb

Comment: It finally worked!!! I was able to use the sqllocaldb cmd line utility to get the information for the new shared instance. Turns out my original connection string was what it needed to be now that it was shared. Thanks for the help and getting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This was fixed thanks to Charlie's comments below. I just needed to change my localDB to a shared instance.

steps taken to resolve:

1. launch cmd line and use sqllocaldb utility to view running databases.

```
>sqllocaldb i
>MSSQLLocalDB
```

2. changed db to shared with

```
 >sqllocaldb h "localDb"
```

Note: Although the new "shared" version of the database now shows as ./localdb, the connection string will still use the unshared name of the server. Why this is, I have no idea.

Also, if like me you have never used command line for sql database management, chances are the utility is already installed if you have a db running on your machine. Just open a command line and put in:

```
sqllocaldb -?
```

This will give you a menu of all the options.

Comment: Might help others if you explained in your answer what steps you took